# Blank worksheets opened up every time Excel starts - accidentally created after splitting Spreadsheet using VBA code

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I need a bit of help with Xcel 2010.

I have a spreadsheet budget workbook in Xcel 2010 that had 6 tabs of worksheets. I needed to make a copy of just one of those worksheets to pass on to someone who was not allowed to see the other worksheets.

I used this VBA code shown below to split up the workbook and it worked just fine. But, since doing so, now every time I open up **any** Xcel file I get three blank worksheets that open up at the same time and they are labeled as Tabelle1.xls, Tabelle2.xls and Tabelle3.xls.

I thought that using another VBA code (see below the other code) to delete the module would take care of that but it did not. Now there is no code/module at all if I open up Visual Basic but I still get three blank worksheets that open up separately from whatever Xcel file I open up. The three blank worksheets all have the .xls file extension but the version of MS Office I have uses .xlsx.

Other info: I am using Windows 7, this is my work computer and do not know anything about VBA coding myself. I was just looking for a quick fix by Googling and got myself in trouble.

**The code to split up the Workbook**

```
Sub Splitbook()
MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
sht.Copy
ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
Filename:=MyPath & "\" & sht.Name & ".xls"
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
Next sht
End Sub
```

**The code I used to delete the module:**

```
Sub DeleteModule()
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent

    Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("Module1")
    VBProj.VBComponents.Remove VBComp
End Sub
```

SectionBreak

Comment: Your code to split the workbook has nothing to do with it. A quick look at it reveals that it has no call to any workbook creation whatsoever, just a call to adding sheets. Do you have, by any chance, a personal macro workbook of sorts somewhere else? Or perhaps you left a `Worksheet_Open` event in one of the sheets? You can check this by double-clicking on each sheet inside VBE.

Comment: The problem is not within your macro code, do you possibly have more code somewhere else? in another module? worksheet open? etc?

Comment: check your XLSTART folder \Users\[x]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART

Comment: Thank you all for your quick responses. I do not understand how or why it happened to begin with since I have never used a macro before and had never opened up Visual Basic before this happened. Thanks to @Cor_Blimey for the answer that successfully deleted the extra worksheets. I will stay away from newbie coding in the future until I can get some proper schooling on the subject.

Comment: @pnuts duly fleshed out the comment into an answer with relevant explanation/links. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

Your symptoms are indicative of a workbook being in the XLSTART folder (an 'autorun' folder). The reason for the names being "Tabelle" are that the source of this workbook was likely a German locale.

Any workbook in this folder is opened whenever the Excel application starts up. It is a folder typically used to place your personal macro workbooks so macros within are automatically available when working on different workbooks.

In your case, this appears unintentional. Check the folder at, typically:

***Win7/8:*** C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART

***WinXP:*** C:\Documents and Settings\[Username]\Application Data\Microsoft\Excel\XLStart

and clear out any files you were not expecting there.

I refer you to http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/customize-how-excel-starts-HP010197489.aspx for more details over how you can customise the templates and workbooks Excel uses to achieve helpful results.